# Spring Netflix Hysterix - not calling fallback method on failure

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to do a very basic example of using hysterix to call a fallback service on failure of the main service. However, when my main service is not available, I just receive a 502 and the running fallback service isn't called.

```
import com.morpheus.reportapi.api.ReportInfo;
import com.morpheus.reportapi.api.ReportValidResponse;
import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Service
public class ReportService {

WebClient masterValidationClient = WebClient.create("<main-service-url>");
WebClient fallbackValidationClient = WebClient.create("<fallback-service-url");

public boolean submitNewReport(ReportInfo reportInfo) {
    ReportValidResponse areReportFieldsValid = getValidationResponse(reportInfo);
    if (!areReportFieldsValid.isValid()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackGetValidationResponse")
private ReportValidResponse getValidationResponse(ReportInfo reportInfo) {
    return masterValidationClient.post().
            uri("/validation")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .body(Mono.just(reportInfo), ReportInfo.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ReportValidResponse.class)
            .block();
}

private ReportValidResponse fallbackGetValidationResponse(ReportInfo reportInfo) {
    return fallbackValidationClient.post().
            uri("/validation")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .body(Mono.just(reportInfo), ReportInfo.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ReportValidResponse.class)
            .block();
}
}
```

Comment: I am using the @EnableHysterix annotation on my application class

Comment: I don't the AOP for `@HystrixCommand` works on private methods. It needs to be in another class. Or put it on  `submitNewReport`

Comment: Thank you, I moved the getValidationResponse to another class and is now working